# Can I get more incense without buying it?

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to capture more Pokémon but I don't want to spend my last incense in Pokémon Go.

If I use it do I get more on pokéstops or do I have to buy them?

(I have walked around and didn't receive an incense from any pokéstop)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to earn the pokecoins by Defender bonus, which will give you 10 for each pokemon assigned in a gym.

You can click the top right circle in the shop tab to get the bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to get incense from pokestops, but you can gain more by leveling up.